# How do I get an array of points of a circle union's circumference

Tags: c#, opengl, math, unity-game-engine, geometry

so I know that The parametric equation for ONE circle is:

```
x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

From this it's easy to get a point from it's circumference...

But what if I want to get the array points of many intersecting circle's **circumference**?
Like this:
[image: Intersected circles]

So how can I draw similar circle unions with GL lines containing **points** (Vertices, sequence matters) in a coordinate system, If I know each circle's center and radius?

(Best would be if you have to iterate trough it using it's collective parametric equation's parameter, to get each Vertex with the desired density.)

Warning! The result is just an array of points (any density) linked with lines as they follow each other (The bold black part). NOT polygons. The shape is not filled.

(I want to draw it in Unity3D using C# and GL.Lines)

Comment: How many circles do you have ? 5, 500, 50000 ?

Comment: 1 ~ 100 and they can fade each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know Circle c1:

```
x1 = cx1 + r1 * cos(a)
y1 = cy1 + r1 * sin(a)
```

and you want additional condition point P[x1,y1] ∉ any other C.
Simply generate all circles(or check the condition when generating) and remove all points that are closer to any Center[cx, cy] then corresponding circle radius R.
To calculate ditance (or better square distance and compare to precalculated square R to improve perforamce) simply measure the distance of vector P - Center(pythagoras):

```
foreach (Point p){
 foreach (other Circle c){
 float dist = (P - Center).Lenght;
 if (dist < c.R){
  // point is not valid, remove
 }
 }
}
```

this solution isnt indeed optimal(as mentioned in comments).
Other approach would be calculate intersections of every circle with every other(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect) and remove **RANGE** between those points(the right one ofc - its starting to be complicated). In addtiotion if you need to maintain right sequence, it should be possible to continue generating one circle untill you reach an intersection - then switch circles for the new one etc. *Carefull though: you would need to start on outside of the shape!*

Comment: good indeed, but it may be a little too heavy for computation

Comment: True its heavy - you are checking for collisions. But if you calculate square distance instead of disatance and precalc square R you can avoid doing sqrt() .

Comment: This would be good solution, but I think it ruins the sequence of the points. Which is important, when we want to link them together, and the result won't be the same as it's on my image :/

Comment: @Z4urce you can calc intersections and generate points until you reach one, then switch the circles and continue on the new one untill you reach another intersection etc. but it smells like hell a lot of math...

Comment: Yep it is. I'm almost desperate. The problem isn't the jump to the next circle. It's that when you don't know any points yet, you can only store these points according to the angle used to calculate it. After we removed the unused points, we start to draw at Zero Pi. as we go trough the circle, we skip the removed points, and the GL will link the last used point with the current. After this, the freshly drawn circle will look like like we cut a slice from it... I hope i was understandable :/

Comment: You either need to connect the parts correctly(meaning you need to match similar end-points of sequences and merge those, which can be dangerous if precision is required). OR precalculate the intersections and start on "safe" point(isnt inside any circle) and start generating points untill you reach intersection - switch the circles. That means you need to find the right new starting angle(the angle where the intersection is on ther other circle) and continue from there on the new circle.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which OpenGL version you want to use, a simple way would be to trace the triangles of each circles in a stencil. Then trace same circles in lines excluding the region in the stencil.

For a shader solution, you can [check here](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dS3RK):

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec3      iResolution;           // viewport resolution (in pixels)
uniform float     iGlobalTime;           // shader playback time (in seconds)
uniform float     iChannelTime[4];       // channel playback time (in seconds)
uniform vec3      iChannelResolution[4]; // channel resolution (in pixels)
uniform vec4      iMouse;                // mouse pixel coords. xy: current (if MLB down), zw: click
uniform samplerXX iChannel0..3;          // input channel. XX = 2D/Cube
uniform vec4      iDate;                 // (year, month, day, time in seconds)
uniform float     iSampleRate;           // sound sample rate (i.e., 44100)

bool PixelInsideCircle( vec3 circle )
{
    return length(vec2(gl_FragCoord.xy - circle.xy)) < circle.z;
}

bool PixelOnCircleContour( vec3 circle )
{
    return PixelInsideCircle(circle) && !PixelInsideCircle( vec3(circle.xy,circle.z-1.0) );
}

void main( void )
{
    float timeFactor = (2.0+sin(iGlobalTime))/2.0;

    const int NB_CIRCLES=3;
    vec3 c[NB_CIRCLES];
    c[0] = vec3( 0.6, 0.4, 0.07 ) * iResolution;
    c[1] = vec3( 0.45, 0.69, 0.09 ) * iResolution;
    c[2] = vec3( 0.35, 0.58, 0.06 ) * iResolution;
    c[0].z = 0.09*iResolution.x*timeFactor;
    c[1].z = 0.1*iResolution.x*timeFactor;
    c[2].z = 0.07*iResolution.x*timeFactor;

    c[0].xy = iMouse.xy;

    bool keep = false;
    for ( int i = 0; i < NB_CIRCLES; ++i )
    {
        if ( !PixelOnCircleContour(c[i]) )
            continue;

        bool insideOther = false;
        for ( int j = 0; j < NB_CIRCLES; ++j )
        {
            if ( i == j )
                continue;

            if ( PixelInsideCircle(c[j]) )
                insideOther = true;
        }

        keep = keep || !insideOther;
    }

    if ( keep )
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0); 
}
```

and tweak it a little

Comment: Sorry if I was equivocal, but I need a solution without any triangle or polygon. Just points (vertices). (The circles doesn't exists, we just know their center and radius.)

Comment: In that case you could discard any fragment of the line falling inside one of the three circles with a simple shader. I'm not sure if your question belongs in OpenGL.

Comment: I updated my shader so we can move one of the circles around and their radii varies

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really complete as you don't explain how you want the points to be spread over the outline. I infer that you would like a dense sequence of points ordered along a single curve.

There is no easy solution to this problem and the resulting shape can be very complex (it can even have holes). You will not spare the computation of intersections between circular arcs and other geometric issues.

One way to address it is to polygonize the circles with sufficient point density and use a polygon union algorithm. The excellent Clipper library comes to mind (http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php).

Another more quick & dirty solution is to work in raster space: create a large white image and paint all your circles in black. Then use a contour following algorithm such as Moore-neighborhood(http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/index.html).

Comment: Really, I want a sequence of points ordered along a single curve.
That clipper lib is awesome. As you've figured out, I need only the vertices from the circumference of my complex shape (Bold black on my image). How can I achieve this with that clipper lib?

Comment: As said, turn your circles into polygons and take their union using Clipper. Clipper will give you the vertices.

Comment: How do I remove the inner faces and edges afterwards?

Comment: You don't need to. The output of Clipper is a list of vertices.

Comment: Are they in order? Can I iterate through them with gl lines and get the outline of the complex object?